# for loop to determine the top 10 percent of values in an interval

Tags: r, for-loop, max, intervals

I essentially have two columns (vectors) with speed and accel in a data.frame as such:

```
    speed     acceleration
1   3.2694444 2.6539535522
2   3.3388889 2.5096979141
3   3.3888889 2.2722134590
4   3.4388889 1.9815256596
5   3.5000000 1.6777544022
6   3.5555556 1.3933215141
7   3.6055556 1.1439051628
8   3.6527778 0.9334115982
9   3.6722222 0.7561602592
```

I need to find for each value speed on the x axis (speed), what is the top 10% max values from the y axis (acceleration). This also needs to be in a specific interval. For example speed 3.2-3.4, 3.4-3.6, and so on. Can you please show me how a for loop would look like in this situation?

Comment: You don't have enough rows per group to make it meaningful in the sample data, and grouping by what looks like a continuous variable without binning first may be a bad idea. With some binning by rounding, maybe `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(speed_binned = round(speed, 1)) %>% summarise(p90 = quantile(acceleration, p = 0.9), p100 = max(acceleration))`

Comment: or maybe `speed_binned = cut(speed, seq(3, 4, .2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @alistaire already pointed out, you have provided a very limited amount of data. So we first have to simulate I a bit more data based on which we can test our code.

```
set.seed(1)

# your data
speed <- c(3.2694444, 3.3388889, 3.3388889, 3.4388889, 3.5,
           3.5555556, 3.6055556, 3.6527778, 3.6722222)
acceleration <- c(2.6539535522, 2.5096979141, 2.2722134590,
                  1.9815256596, 1.6777544022, 1.3933215141,
                  1.1439051628, 0.9334115982, 0.7561602592)
df <- data.frame(speed, acceleration)

# expand data.frame and add a little bit of noise to all values
# to make them 'unique'
df <- as.data.frame(do.call(
  rbind,
  replicate(15L, apply(df, 2, \(x) (x + runif(length(x), -1e-1, 1e-1) )),
            simplify = FALSE)
))
```

The function `create_intervals`, as the name suggests, creates user-defined intervals. The rest of the code does the 'heavy lifting' and stores the desired result in `out`.

If you would like to have intervals of `speed` with equal widths, simply specify the number of groups (`n_groups`) you would like to have and leave the rest of the arguments (i.e. `lwr`, `upr`, and `interval_span`) unspecified.

```
# Cut speed into user-defined intervals
create_intervals <- \(n_groups = NULL, lwr = NULL, upr = NULL, interval_span = NULL) {
  if (!is.null(lwr) & !is.null(upr) & !is.null(interval_span) & is.null(n_groups)) {
    speed_low <- subset(df, speed < lwr, select = speed)
    first_interval <- with(speed_low, c(min(speed), lwr))
    middle_intervals <- seq(lwr + interval_span, upr - interval_span, interval_span)
    speed_upp <- subset(df, speed > upr, select = speed)
    last_interval <- with(speed_upp, c(upr, max(speed)))
    intervals <- c(first_interval, middle_intervals, last_interval)
  } else {
    step <- with(df, c(max(speed) - min(speed))/n_groups)
    intervals <- array(0L, dim = n_groups)
    for(i in seq_len(n_groups)) {
      intervals[i] <- min(df$speed) + i * step
    }
  }
  return(intervals)
}

# three intervals with equal width
my_intervals <- create_intervals(n_groups = 3L)

# Compute values of speed when acceleration is greater then
# or equal to the 90th percentile 
out <- lapply(1:(length(my_intervals)-1L), \(i) {
  x <- subset(df, speed >= my_intervals[i] & speed <= my_intervals[i+1L])
  x[x$acceleration >= quantile(x$acceleration, 0.9), ]
})

# function to round values to two decimal places
r <- \(x) format(round(x, 2), nsmall = 2L)

# assign names to each element of out
for(i in seq_along(out)) {
  names(out)[i] <- paste0(r(my_intervals[i]), '-', r(my_intervals[i+1L]))
}
```

**Output 1**

```
> out
$`3.38-3.57`
       speed acceleration
11  3.394378     2.583636
21  3.383631     2.267659
57  3.434123     2.300234
83  3.394886     2.580924
101 3.395459     2.460971

$`3.57-3.76`
      speed acceleration
6  3.635234     1.447290
41 3.572868     1.618293
51 3.615017     1.420020
95 3.575412     1.763215
```

We could also compute the desired values of `speed` based on intervals that make more 'sense' than just equally spaced speed intervals, e.g. [`min(speed)`, 3.3), [3.3, 3.45), [3.45, 3.6), and [3.6, `max(speed)`).

This can be accomplished by leaving `n_groups` unspecified and instead specify `lwr`, `upr`, and an `interval_span` that makes sense. For instance, it makes sense to have a interval span of 0.15 when the lower limit is 3.3 and the upper limit is 3.6.

```
# custom boundaries based on a lower limit and upper limit
my_intervals <- create_intervals(lwr = 3.3, upr = 3.6, interval_span = 0.15)
```

**Output 2**

```
> out
$`3.18-3.30`
      speed acceleration
37 3.238781     2.696456
82 3.258691     2.722076

$`3.30-3.45`
      speed acceleration
11 3.394378     2.583636
19 3.328292     2.711825
73 3.315306     2.644580
83 3.394886     2.580924

$`3.45-3.60`
      speed acceleration
4  3.520530     2.018930
40 3.517329     2.032943
58 3.485247     2.079893
67 3.458031     2.078545

$`3.60-3.76`
      speed acceleration
6  3.635234     1.447290
34 3.688131     1.218969
51 3.615017     1.420020
78 3.628465     1.348873
```

Note: use `function(x)` instead of `\(x)` if you use a version of R <4.1.0

Comment: ! this is perfect!!! exactly what I needed :) it works perfectly. My actual data set holds > 20 000 observations so in my case no need to expand data (but good to know for the future). Thank you as well alistaire