# How to generate covariate-adjusted cox survival/hazard functions?

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression, survminer

I'm using the `survminer` package to try to generate survival and hazard function graphs for a longitudinal student-level dataset that has 5 subgroups of interest.

I've had success creating a model that shows the survival functions *without* adjusting for student-level covariates using `ggsurvplot`.

```
ggsurvplot(survfit(Surv(expectedgr, sped) ~ langstatus_new, data=mydata), pvalue=TRUE)
```

[Output example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6r3ze.png)

However, I cannot manage to get these curves adjusted for covariates. My aim is to create [graphs like these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMaga.jpg). As you can see, these are covariate-adjusted survival curves according to some factor variable. Does anyone how such graphs can be obtained in `R`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although correct, I believe that the method described in the answer of Dion Groothof is not what is usually of interest. Usually, researchers are interested in visualizing the causal effect of a variable *adjusted* for confounders. Simply showing the predicted survival curve for one single covariate combination does not really do the trick here. I would recommend reading up on confounder-adjusted survival curves. See https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.10002 for example.

Those type of curves can be calculated in R using the `adjustedCurves` package: https://github.com/RobinDenz1/adjustedCurves

In your example, the following code could be used:

```
library(survival)
library(devtools)

# install adjustedCurves from github, load it
devtools::install_github("/RobinDenz1/adjustedCurves")
library(adjustedCurves)

# "event" needs to be binary
lung$status <- lung$status - 1

# "variable" needs to be a factor
lung$ph.ecog <- factor(lung$ph.ecog)

fit <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~  ph.ecog + age + sex, data=lung,
             x=TRUE)

# calculate and plot curves
adj <- adjustedsurv(data=lung, variable="ph.ecog", ev_time="time",
                    event="status", method="direct",
                    outcome_model=fit, conf_int=TRUE)
plot(adj)
```

Producing the following output:

[image: Output]

These survival curves are adjusted for the effect of `age` and `sex`. More information on how this adjustment works can be found in the documentation of the `adjustedCurves` package or the article I cited above.

Comment: My solution actually provides the user with the confounder-adjusted expected survival probabilities, obtained by non-parametrically estimating the baseline hazard with the Breslow estimator behind the scences. I explicitly commented in the R code on the fact that the user has to "#specify for which combinations of values of age, sex, and # ph.karno we want to derive survival probabilies"

Comment: Yes, but it is not the kind of average treatment effect that is usually of interest. If you are interested only in some conditional effects (such as the survival probability for a person aged 42, male, who received a chemotherapy or something), your approach is probably the best way to do it. Usually, however, we are more interested in the survival probability at some time t that would have been observed if all people in the sample would have received therapy x, which is what the `adjustedCurves` package estimates.

Answer (score 2):

You want to obtain survival probabilities from a Cox model for certain values of some covariate of interest, while adjusting for other covariates. However, because we do not make any assumption on the distribution of the survival times in a Cox model, we cannot directly obtain survival probabilities from it. We first have to estimate the baseline hazard function, which is typically done with the non-parametric Breslow estimator. When the Cox model is fitted with `coxph` from the `survival` package, we can obtain such probabilites with a call to the `survfit()` function. You may consult `?survfit.coxph` for more information.

Let's see how we can do this by using the `lung` data set.

```
library(survival)

# select covariates of interest
df <- subset(lung, select = c(time, status, age, sex, ph.karno))

# assess whether there are any missing observations
apply(df, 2, \(x) sum(is.na(x))) # 1 in ph.karno

# listwise delete missing observations
df <- df[complete.cases(df), ]

# Cox model
fit <- coxph(Surv(time, status == 2) ~ age + sex + ph.karno, data = df)

## Note that I ignore the fact that ph.karno does not satisfy the PH assumption.

# specify for which combinations of values of age, sex, and 
# ph.karno we want to derive survival probabilies
ND1 <- with(df, expand.grid(
  age = median(age),
  sex = c(1,2),
  ph.karno = median(ph.karno)
))
ND2 <- with(df, expand.grid(
  age = median(age),
  sex = 1, # males
  ph.karno = round(create_intervals(n_groups = 3L))
))

# Obtain the expected survival times
sfit1 <- survfit(fit, newdata = ND1)
sfit2 <- survfit(fit, newdata = ND2)
```

The code behind the function `create_intervals()` can be found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70660638/10852113). I just simply replaced `speed` with `ph.karno` in the function.

The output `sfit1` contains the expected median survival times and the corresponding 95% confidence intervals for the combinations of covariates as specified in `ND1`.

```
> sfit1
Call: survfit(formula = fit, newdata = ND)

    n events median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL
1 227    164    283     223     329
2 227    164    371     320     524
```

Survival probabilities at specific follow-up times be obtained with the `times` argument of the `summary()` method.

```
# survival probabilities at 200 days of follow-up
summary(sfit1, times = 200)
```

The output contains again the expected survival probability, but now after 200 days of follow-up, wherein `survival1` corresponds to the expected survival probability of the first row of `ND1`, i.e. a male and female patient of median `age` with median `ph.karno`.

```
> summary(sfit1, times = 200)
Call: survfit(formula = fit, newdata = ND1)

 time n.risk n.event survival1 survival2
  200    144      71     0.625     0.751
```

The 95% confidence limits associated with these two probabilities can be manually extracted from `summary()`.

```
sum_sfit <- summary(sfit1, times = 200)
sum_sfit <- t(rbind(sum_sfit$surv, sum_sfit$lower, sum_sfit$upper))
colnames(sum_sfit) <- c("S_hat", "2.5 %", "97.5 %")
# ------------------------------------------------------
> sum_sfit
      S_hat     2.5 %    97.5 %
1 0.6250586 0.5541646 0.7050220
2 0.7513961 0.6842830 0.8250914
```

If you would like to use `ggplot` to depict the expected survival probabilities (and the corresponding 95% confidence intervals) for the combinations of values as specified in `ND1` and `ND2`, we first need to make `data.frame`s that contain all the information in an appropriate format.

```
# function which returns the output from a survfit.object
# in an appropriate format, which can be used in a call
# to ggplot()
df_fun <- \(surv_obj, newdata, factor) {
  len <- length(unique(newdata[[factor]]))
  out <- data.frame(
    time = rep(surv_obj[['time']], times = len),
    n.risk = rep(surv_obj[['n.risk']], times = len),
    n.event = rep(surv_obj[['n.event']], times = len),
    surv = stack(data.frame(surv_obj[['surv']]))[, 'values'],
    upper = stack(data.frame(surv_obj[['upper']]))[, 'values'],
    lower = stack(data.frame(surv_obj[['lower']]))[, 'values']
  )
  out[, 7] <- gl(len, length(surv_obj[['time']]))
  names(out)[7] <- 'factor'
  return(out)
}

# data for the first panel (A)
df_leftPanel <- df_fun(surv_obj = sfit1, newdata = ND1, factor = 'sex')

# data for the second panel (B)
df_rightPanel <- df_fun(surv_obj = sfit2, newdata = ND2, factor = 'ph.karno')
```

Now that we have defined our `data.frame`s, we need to define a new function which allows us to plot the 95% CIs. We assign it the generic name `geom_stepribbon`.

```
library(ggplot2)

# Function for geom_stepribbon
geom_stepribbon <- function(
  mapping     = NULL,
  data        = NULL,
  stat        = "identity",
  position    = "identity",
  na.rm       = FALSE,
  show.legend = NA,
  inherit.aes = TRUE, ...) {
  layer(
    data        = data,
    mapping     = mapping,
    stat        = stat,
    geom        = GeomStepribbon,
    position    = position,
    show.legend = show.legend,
    inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params      = list(na.rm = na.rm, ... )
  )
}

GeomStepribbon <- ggproto(
  "GeomStepribbon", GeomRibbon,
  extra_params = c("na.rm"),
  draw_group = function(data, panel_scales, coord, na.rm = FALSE) {
    if (na.rm) data <- data[complete.cases(data[c("x", "ymin", "ymax")]), ]
    data   <- rbind(data, data)
    data   <- data[order(data$x), ]
    data$x <- c(data$x[2:nrow(data)], NA)
    data   <- data[complete.cases(data["x"]), ]
    GeomRibbon$draw_group(data, panel_scales, coord, na.rm = FALSE)
  }
)
```

Finally, we can plot the expected survival probabilities for `ND1` and `ND2`.

```
yl <- 'Expected Survival probability\n'
xl <- '\nTime (days)'

# left panel
my_colours <- c('blue4', 'darkorange')
adj_colour <- \(x) adjustcolor(x, alpha.f = 0.2)
my_colours <- c(
  my_colours, adj_colour(my_colours[1]), adj_colour(my_colours[2])
)
left_panel <- ggplot(df_leftPanel,
                     aes(x = time, colour = factor, fill = factor)) + 
  geom_step(aes(y = surv), size = 0.8) + 
  geom_stepribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), colour = NA) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = 'Sex',
                      values = c('1' = my_colours[1],
                                 '2' = my_colours[2]),
                      labels = c('1' = 'Males',
                                 '2' = 'Females')) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = 'Sex',
                    values = c('1' = my_colours[3],
                               '2' = my_colours[4]),
                    labels = c('1' = 'Males',
                               '2' = 'Females')) +
  ylab(yl) + xlab(xl) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.position = 'top')

# right panel
my_colours <- c('blue4', 'darkorange', '#00b0a4')
my_colours <- c(
  my_colours, adj_colour(my_colours[1]),
  adj_colour(my_colours[2]), adj_colour(my_colours[3])
)
right_panel <- ggplot(df_rightPanel,
                      aes(x = time, colour = factor, fill = factor)) + 
  geom_step(aes(y = surv), size = 0.8) +  
  geom_stepribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), colour = NA) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = 'Ph.karno',
                      values = c('1' = my_colours[1],
                                 '2' = my_colours[2],
                                 '3' = my_colours[3]),
                      labels = c('1' = 'Low',
                                 '2' = 'Middle',
                                 '3' = 'High')) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = 'Ph.karno',
                    values = c('1' = my_colours[4],
                               '2' = my_colours[5],
                               '3' = my_colours[6]),
                    labels = c('1' = 'Low',
                               '2' = 'Middle',
                               '3' = 'High')) +
  ylab(yl) + xlab(xl) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.position = 'top')

# composite plot
library(ggpubr)
ggarrange(left_panel, right_panel,
          ncol = 2, nrow = 1,
          labels = c('A', 'B'))
```

**Output**

[image]

**Interpretation**

- Panel A shows the expected survival probabilities for a male and female patient of median `age` with a median `ph.karno`.
- Panel B shows the expected survival probabilities for three male patients of median `age` with `ph.karno`s of 67 (low), 83 (middle), and 100 (high).

These survival curves will always satisfy the PH assumption, as they were derived from the Cox model.

Note: use `function(x)` instead of `\(x)` if you use a version of R <4.1.0

Comment: Hi Dion,Thanks so much for your explanation. How would the code look different when I have more than 2 groups in my data that I want to examine? (more than just males vs females).

Comment: @ohminoh Would it help if I also incorporate a graph showing the expected survival probs for three equal cut points of `lung$ph.karno`?

Comment: Hi Dion, ph.karno in this dataset is not a categorical variable, right? In my dataset, the outcome of interest is a binary variable. I wonder how the R syntax would need to be different given this?

Comment: But you just said that you "have more than 2 groups in my data", so I thought I could just show you how to obtain survival probs when you covariate of interest has >2 levels.

Comment: Hi, yes I do. I misunderstood you--yes I'd love to see that. It'd be helpful :)

Comment: @ohminoh I have edited the post accordingly. If this solved your problem, you may accept it as answer by clicking the checkmark. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much! I will read through this but the graph looks like what I've been looking for. I do have just one more question for you--If I want to generate a hazard function graph (instead of survival function shown in your example), what additions would I include in the syntax?

Comment: You mean the cumulative incidence?

Comment: Yep the cumulative hazard plots. I want to generate graphs that show the survival probabilities, and another graph for the hazard functions (i.e., that show the probabilities of being identified for an outcome of interest for the particular time period for those who have not yet been identified for the outcome condition). Does that make sense? Apologies if I'm unclear--this is my first time giving this a go! I really appreciate your help so far.

Comment: No worries ;-) This is very easy to accomplish. Simply change `aes(y = surv)` in `geom_step()` to `aes(y = 1 - surv)` and `aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper)` in `geom_stepribbon()` to `aes(ymin = 1 - lower, ymax = 1 - upper)`. And, of course, make sure to change the `ylab` as well.

Comment: Thank you! I will try out the syntax tonight. I appreciate your help!!